# How Do I Set The "Print directly to the printer" attribute on an IPP Printer in Windows 7 x64 with PrintUIEntry?

Tags: cmd, windows-7-x64, rundll32

**Summary**

I'm trying to automate a script for Windows 7 x64 to set the "Print directly to the printer" attribute on an IPP Printer I've created (see screenshot below)

[image]

I've tried `rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "PrinterName" attributes +direct` as suggested [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/745efb9b-7565-4aad-b7cf-a2369d995828/change-from-quotprint-directly-to-the-printerquot-to-quotspool-print-documents-so-program?forum=winserverprint), but I get the error **The arguments are invalid**

Comment: I was able to get the command to work on a network printer: `rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "\\http://localhost:1234\PrinterName" attributes +direct`. Still no luck on the non-network printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After beating my head against this for 2 weeks, I came across the solution:

PrintUIEntry has an "undocumented switch": `/x`. This must be present for the initial printer installation.

> An undocumented /x switch is required to map an IPP printer. (Content ID 314486)

[source](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2011/09/16/print-queue-scripting/)

---

Ultimately, that's all that needed to be added.

```
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /if /f %windir%\\inf\\ntprint.inf /r “http://localhost:<port>/” /m “<drivername>” /b ”<PrinterName>” /n “<PrinterName>” /q /Y /z /u /x

rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "<PrinterName>" attributes +direct`
```